# javascript - indexOf is not a funciton

Tags: javascript

I have this event...

```
   <textarea id="chat"> </textarea>
   <button type="button" onclick="play_song();">talk</button>
```

... triggering the following `function`:

```
   var input = function() {
           var chat = document.getElementById("chat").value.split(" ");
           return chat && console.log(chat);
        }
```

then there's this `function`:

```
   function setIntersection(a, b) {

      var result = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         if (b.indexOf(a[i]) !== -1 && result.indexOf(a[i]) === -1) {
            result.push(a[i]);
         }
      }
    return result;
   }
```

a `prototype function`:

```
   Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect = function(input) {


      var bestSong = null;
      var bestCount = -Infinity;

      for (var i in songs) {
        var currentCount = setIntersection(songs[i].lyrics, input).length;

    if (currentCount > bestCount) {
        bestSong = songs[i];
        bestCount = currentCount;
    }
}

return bestSong && bestSong.name;
}
```

the code ends here:

```
   function play_song() {

    var id = Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect(input);
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.play();
}
```

but `console.log` returns: `Uncaught TypeError: b.indexOf is not a function`

if I test `var input = ["one", "two"];`, however, I get the intersection done on the code depending on `input`.

what am I missing?

Comment: Whats b? Maybe your setting it wrong

Comment: How are the HTML and `input` function related to the issue? Instead, you should post how you call `setIntersection`.

Comment: Note that: `return chat && console.log(chat);` returns undefined, since that's the return value of *console.log*.

Comment: You are passing *input* as the *b* parameter. *input* is a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var currentCount = setIntersection(songs[i].lyrics, input).length;
```

should be

```
var currentCount = setIntersection(songs[i].lyrics, input()).length;
```

this also relies on input being corrected as follows

```
var input = function() {
   var chat = document.getElementById("chat").value.split(" ");
   return chat;
}
```

Comment: This is better than my answer I suppose. This will make your b an array and thus won't throw the typerror problem.

Comment: @RobG it will work as long as input is changed to return the array as probably intended - see edited answer

Comment: @Jaromanda X `input` is still `undefined`, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JaromandaX  I had forgot to run `input();` after the function expression. now It's not `undefined` anymore and it works.

Answer (score 3):

> what am I missing?

Here, you declare *input* as a global and assign a function:

```
var input = function() {
    var chat = document.getElementById("chat").value.split(" ");
    return chat && console.log(chat);
}
```

I much prefer function declarations, but each to their own.

Here you pass *input* as a parameter to *Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect*

```
var id = Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect(input);
```

which assigns it to its own variable *input*:

```
Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect = function(input) {
```

and then calls *setIntersection*:

```
    var currentCount = setIntersection(songs[i].lyrics, input).length;
```

Then in *setIntersection* it's assigned to the *b* parameter:

```
function setIntersection(a, b) {
```

and treated like an array:

```
     if (b.indexOf(a[i]) !== -1 && result.indexOf(a[i]) === -1) {
```

Comment: @RobG I figured that a `declaration function` would set `input` as a `global variable`, which is passed as `parameter` inside the other `functions`. how would you do it using a `function declaration` instead, minding that I need an `array` as a result?

Comment: Function declarations are effectively also variable declarations of the function name. The only real difference is that they are processed before any code is executed, whereas for a variable declaration with assignment, while the declaration happens before execution, the assignment only happens when that line of code is executed. There must be many questions here on `function name(){}` vs `var name=function(){}`.

Comment: @RobG I see, function declaration is processed when the script is parsed, not on run-time, is that it? so, with a function declaration I wouldn't need to add this line `input();` after the variable declaration with assignement (which I needed to do after declaring the variable input)?

Comment: @data_garden—yes. Since function declarations are processed before execution, you can declare the function at the very bottom and call it at the very top. Not so with assignments, they must be called after the assignment.

Comment: For using a function declaration, just do `function returnChat() { ... }`, then `var input = returnChat()`. It's MUCH better to do this because 1) as was said, the function will be ran and have a value on page load, and be waiting for your line to call it without having to take cycles.  2) Nothing to declare globally. You just create the function & call it. 3) In C#, you typically HAVE to know the type of the variable you are passing around. You don't want to assign an anonymous function to variables & not know it, but have their type declared instead. Better to get used to doing it like this.

Answer (score 1):

For you to be able to use `indexOf` function of `Array` object then your `b` variable has to be an `array`. Check your `b` type.

Here is the [doc regarding Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/indexOf) function

**EDIT:**

With the information you have provided it seems your `b` is a reference to `input`. You need to make sure `input` is an `array`. In the case you have provided.. `input` is actually a function and not an `array`.

Comment: "The" current documentation for *Array.prototype.indexOf* is actually in [*ECMA-262 ed6*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.indexof). ;-)

Comment: @RobG well noted. It hasn't been implemented across all browsers though?

Comment: @Grimbode yes. `console.log` returns me an `array`.

Comment: @Grimbode—if by "it" you mean *Array.prototype.indexOf*, it was introduced in ES5 so should be in all browsers in use except IE8 I think. If you mean ECMA-262 ed 6, I don't think any browser has fully implemented it yet, but most new browsers have most of it. I referenced ECMA-262 ed 6 because it's been the standard for more than a month. ES5 is 4 years old. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify the example as much as possible, your function (as already noted) is not invoked with the expected arguments (presumably wrong logic). As for the `indexOf` method:

```
typeof [].indexOf // "function"

typeof ''.indexOf // "function"
```

Any data type which implements the [iteration protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) should support `indexOf`.